# how to send text message or phone call just like the eclipse emulator does

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

I'm making a program that is based on sending many notifications to the phone. I have come across a problem with making the phone act like its an actual call or message anyone know any other way to achieve this?

I need the text `message/call` to come from the program but when it appears on the phone to act like it's a real sms `message/call`. Like the emulator Control does in Eclipse.

I have tried Telephonymanager over and over and the closest I have come is trying to fake it with a notification Manager.

---

ok so Let me explain this better I need to make an activity where my program sends a real text message and phone call to the phone. any ideas? (Like someone else is sending it to the phone)

Comment: Not sure about others, but I'm not sure what you want to do... maybe you could provide a better explanation??

Comment: Well Androidsterz you may try reading DDMS source code or using ddms.jar may work for you.

Comment: I will try the DDMS source code I never even thought about that. I thought it was just compiled with the eclipse.....I will let you know how it works out.

Comment: where do i find the source code for DDMS? do I have to download it? and ddms.jar is not in my computer..